# Как передать JSON в GET в Python

Tags: python, ajax, json, get

Есть реализованная функция REST-API в Flask
Метод GET принимает в data JSON объект для сортировки результата

```
@self.server.route('api/questions', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        def questions():
            try:
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    # Функция вставки или изменения объекта
                else:
                    # Функция запроса объектов
                    req = request.get_json()                    
                    return JSON, 200
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Данная функция работает отлично, если отправлять из postman
А вот если через браузер нет...

На стороне браузера:

```
object = { "type": { "tag": ['1','2','3'] } }
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/questions',
            type: 'GET',            
            data: JSON.stringify(object),
            content-type: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
```

Подскажите, что я не так делаю или стоит добавить.

P.S. Пробовал собрать запрос через $.getJSON, XmlHTTPRequest, fetch

Comment: Из доки по полю `data` в `jquery`: `If the HTTP method is one that cannot have an entity body, such as GET, the data is appended to the URL.`

Comment: А как тогда правильно?
Как я понимаю на стороне сервера проверять пришел json в дате или параметрами
И если параметрами, то он приходит /api/questions?{JSON}
Как тогда его распарсить?